# Renaming my iOS project and GoogleFirebaseMessage

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an iOS project with PUSH notifications using GoogleFirebaseMessaging, it worked ok for me (I got messages in "background" and "foreground" modes).
Then I renamed the project in XCode, after that I'm not receiving messages in "background" mode totally.
How I can fix it?
PS: I'm using cocoaPods. Tried to rename back - same results.
Thanx

Comment: Did the rename affect the bundle ID of the app?

Comment: Maybe, but I can't rename bundle ID in my project. I've solved the problem  - recreate a new project with same name in another place on my hard disk.

Comment: Same effect if you'll rename your name in AppleDeveloper account, but in this case you should recreate certificates and apply a new one to GoogleFIrebaseCOnsole.